# LaTeX twocolumnproof Package

Tags: packages

I found this really nice way to write two column geometry proof for high school, but I can't seem to find the package. It isn't showing up in MikTeX 2.9 and Google doesn't show any information. Here is the example of the package at Overleaf.

[Two Column Proof](https://www.overleaf.com/8714352kpdfryxydzfy#/31070254/)

```
\usepackage{TwoColumnProof}

\title{Two-Column Proof Example}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{sampleproof}

\section*{Given:}
\begin{itemize}
\item Segment AD bisects segment $BC$.
\item Segment BC bisects segment $AD$. 
\end{itemize}

\section*{Prove:}
\begin{itemize}
\item $\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle DCM$ are congruent. 
\end{itemize}

\begin{TwoColumnProof}
\StatementReason{Segment $AD$ bisects segment $BC$.}
{Given.}

\StatementReason{Segments $AM$ and $MD$ are congruent. \label{label1}}
{When a segment is bisected, the two resulting segments are congruent.}

\StatementReason{Segment $BC$ bisects segment $AD$.}
{Given.}

\StatementReason{Segments $BM$ and $CM$ are congruent.}
{When a segment is bisected, the two resulting segments are congruent.}

\StatementReason{$\angle AMB$ and $\angle DMC$ are congruent.}
{Verticle angles are congruent.}

\StatementReason{$\triangle ABM$ and $\triangle DCM$ are congruent.}
{SAS postulate (2, 4, 5).}
\end{TwoColumnProof}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It's a custom package. If you open up the left panel (Project tab) in Overleaf, you'll see the `TwoColumnProof.sty` file in the same folder as the source `.tex` file. You need to download it from Overleaf, afaik it's not on CTAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `twocolumnproof` package is a custom package. If you open up the left panel (Project tab) in Overleaf, you'll see the `TwoColumnProof.sty` file in the same folder as the source .tex file. You need to download it from Overleaf if you want to compile this particular MWE outside of Overleaf. As far as I know, it's not on CTAN.

Here's an image of where I found the `.sty` file:

[image: overleaf example]